# How to break line in JSX from javascript string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have string that I use in JSX

```js
const text = 'Hello World';
```

and JSX:

```
<p>{text}</p>
```

How to start new line from `World` ?

I want result:

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: This is for example, I have quite big data

Comment: What do you mean by "new line"? When rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using separate HTML elements for each line would be a better approach, this requires some css to ensure there vertically, this could look something like the following:

```js
const Example = () => {
  
    const text = 'Hello World';
    
    return <p>{text.split(' ').map(t => <span>{t}</span>)}</p>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

Otherwise, we can use [`split(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to add linebreaks (`<br />`) between each word.

```js
const Example = () => {
  
    const text = 'Hello World';
    const wrapped = text.split(' ')
                    .reduce((prev, cur) => [ ...prev, cur, <br /> ], [])
    
    return <p>{wrapped}</p>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, i did run a jsbench.me on `split.join` and `replaceAll` and `replaceAll` ended up being 61.97% slower on average

Comment: Yea you'r right, improved my answer, giving OP 2 options, add elements with css or use the <br>

Comment: Benchmarking this is the definition of premature optimisation. @SamuelHulla

Answer (score -1):

```
 <div>{text.split(' ').map( w => <p>{w}</p>)}</div
```